# How do I connect potentiometers to a power supply so that I can use one to vary current and the other to vary voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current, power-electronics, potentiometer

I want to connect **two** **potentiometers** in a way that will allow me use one to **vary the output voltage and the other to vary the output current,** I'm getting confused about connecting this.

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you attempted so far? Show us that you've put effort into this task, and where you're stuck.

Comment: Can you tell us what the intended load is and do you have a good understanding of Ohm’s law?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is equivalent to:

> I've got a throttle handle and a brake handle, how do I hook them up so that I can control speed and acceleration?

You're asking how to build a motorcycle, when all you got is a small part of the handlebars.

The electronic equivalent - what you're actually asking for - is a current- and voltage-controlled power supply, also called "constant current - constant voltage supply" or "CV/CC supply". There are plenty of such circuits, of various degrees of complication, available online, to give you some idea of what's involved.

Depending on what kind of homework does the question come from, the answer can be as simple as "one potentiometer's output voltage goes to a voltage-controlled current source, another to a voltage-controlled voltage source". But if the question really asks "how to hook it up", you'll need to come up with a circuit of some sort.

A rudimentary low power linear power supply with adjustable voltage and current takes a couple transistors. Better ones will need transistors and op-amps, or a couple dozen transistors in place of op-amps.